# How can I get a max values in a query sparql

Tags: sparql

I'd like to know how can I get the MAX values in a sparql query after I applied a count in another SELECT. My code is:

```
#PREFIX nobel: <http://data.nobelprize.org/terms/>
#PREFIX cat: <http://data.nobelprize.org/resource/category/>
#PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
#PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
#PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
#PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
#PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
#PREFIX afn: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/function#>
#PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

Select ?advisorName (max (?c) as ?m ) {#the answer is empty.. )
SELECT ?advisorName (count (distinct (?category)) as ?c) (max (?c) as ?m) { 
     ?student a nobel:Laureate ;
            owl:sameAs ?dbpStudent ;
            foaf:name ?studentName ;
            nobel:nobelPrize ?pStudent .          
     ?pStudent nobel:category ?category .   

FILTER (afn:namespace(?dbpStudent) = str(dbr:))        
SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {    
{ ?dbpStudent dbo:doctoralAdvisor ?dbpAdvisor .}
union
{?dbpAdvisor dbo:doctoralStudent ?dbpStudent.  }    
 ?dbpAdvisor rdfs:label ?advisorName  .
Filter (lang(?advisorName)= "en")   }}
group by ?dbpStudent ?advisorName
order by desc (?c)  }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, as you may know Stack Overflow is not a free coding service, so please let us know what have you already tried and then the help will come. More useful tips on how to make question great can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you have ` (max (?c) as ?m) ` also in the sub-SELECT? And does the sub-SELECT return the expected values?

Comment: And why do you group by `?dbpStudent ` in the outer query? In general, the whole query is non-standard SPARQL ... the triple store that you're using should fail to parse the query.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm sorry for that. I'm reading how I should use sparql :)

Comment: No worries, basic SPARQL is simple, more complex tasks can indeed be complicated. And sometimes, it's even not possible to do it with a single SPARQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is  not an answer but used as a more complex comment!

Before we can start debugging, your query should be in standard SPARQL syntax:

```
SELECT  ?advisorName (MAX(?c) AS ?m)
WHERE
  { { SELECT  ?advisorName (COUNT(DISTINCT ?category) AS ?c)
      WHERE
        { ?student  rdf:type          nobel:Laureate ;
                    owl:sameAs        ?dbpStudent ;
                    foaf:name         ?studentName ;
                    nobel:nobelPrize  ?pStudent .
          ?pStudent  nobel:category   ?category
          FILTER ( afn:namespace(?dbpStudent) = str(dbr:) )
          SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>
            {   { ?dbpStudent  dbo:doctoralAdvisor  ?dbpAdvisor }
              UNION
                { ?dbpAdvisor  dbo:doctoralStudent  ?dbpStudent }
              ?dbpAdvisor  rdfs:label  ?advisorName
              FILTER ( lang(?advisorName) = "en" )
            }
        }
      GROUP BY ?advisorName
    }
  }
GROUP BY ?advisorName
ORDER BY DESC(?c)
```

Something that I didn't understand:

- why you had a `group by` on the variable `?dbpStudent` in the outer SELECT query as there is no such binding because it's not returned by the inner SELECT query
- why you did compute the MAX also in the inner SELECT query

So my question would be, what is the overall goal of the query?

1. If you want the overall number of Nobel categories for each advisor, you should use the SUM.
2. If you want the highest number an advisor could get through any of his/her students, ...
3. If you want ...

Once we decided on what exactly your query should do, we can start to debug by checking intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks u so much. This is my first time with sparql and I dont understand many things. I'm really sorry for that code :S.

Comment: Does it work for you now? What do you want to have as the final result of your query?